# Radar chart Display legend

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, splunk, splunk-sdk

I cannot find options (radarOptions) to display a legend in my chart using chart.js in Splunk environment.

This doesn't work for me:

```
options: {
    legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
            fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
        }
    }
}
```

My code is below:

```js
    var radarChartData = {
      labels: ["Python", "DevOps", "BI"],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        fill: true,
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: testData[0]
      }, {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        fill: true,
        fillColor: "rgba(101,197,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: testData[1]
      }]
    }

    return radarChartData;
  },

  // Override this method to put the Splunk data into the view
  updateView: function(viz, radarData) {
    // Set radar chart options
    var radarOptions = {
      scaleOverride: true,
      scaleSteps: 10,
      scaleStepWidth: 1,
      scaleStartValue: 0,
      scaleShowLabels: true,
      datasetFill: true,
      scaleShowLabelBackdrop: true,
    };


    // Create the radar chart
    var myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById(mychartid).getContext("2d")).Radar(radarData, radarOptions); /*radarData,radarOption*/
  }

});
```

Please help. How is called the option for displaying legends. Neither `legend: true` nor `legendDisplay:true` work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by upgrading Chart js to the latest version.